# BitmapShader shows black background instead of bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, bitmapshader

In My app, I use a bitmap shader in order to create a round profile image,

this works well, however in the Asus Padfone Infinity it renders as a black circle.

attached the code snippet from my custom ImageView:

```
        circularBitmapShader = new BitmapShader((Bitmap) this.bitmapData.bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        circularPaint.setShader(circularBitmapShader);
        circularPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
        circularBitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(matrix);
        bitmapRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        if (clipCircleRadius == -1) {
            canvas.drawRoundRect(bitmapRect, bitmapRect.width() / 2, bitmapRect.height() / 2, circularPaint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawRoundRect(bitmapRect, clipCircleRadius, clipCircleRadius, circularPaint);
        }
```

Comment: what is `alpha`, what is `matrix` ?

Comment: alpha is dynamic, passed as a parameter.
matrix at this point is just the matrix we work on (after scaling)

Comment: is it 0? what is `matrix` ?, btw why dont you use `RoundedBitmapDrawable` ?

Comment: 0,0 refers to where the rect is starting, I didn't try using the RoundedBitmapDrawable. I'm looking to see why the BitmapShader is not working on this particular device.

Comment: then for testing dont use alpha and matrix first and see what happens

Comment: first thing i tried , still no difference

Comment: if it still doesnt work try to call canvas.drawBitmap() with this.bitmapData.bitmap and see what happens

Comment: also try to `Log.d` the `bitmapRect`

Comment: problem solved, it resided somewhere else, Bitmap shader works perfectly on all version.

Comment: So what was wrong? bitmapData.bitmap was a black Bitmap?

Comment: no, there was another drawable which was the white border around it and it didn't have a "solid", only stroke. It's a known bug for some devices